# CSS background-color not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-color

I got this background-color here

```
-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #0043A1 0%, #0043A1 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

but it will not work in google chrome, any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks,
J

Comment: `-moz` is a mozilla specific prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace with

```
linear-gradient(center top , #0043A1 0%, #0043A1 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

-moz-* css properties are specific to mozilla. They're useful while a property isn't normalized but now (with CSS3) you may use the standardized `linear-gradient`.

Even the Mozilla documentation now [documents linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient).

Comment: This. And to easily build cross-browser gradients, you can use this tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Chrome and Safari browsers:

```
-webkit-linear-gradient
```

And use this for Mozilla (Firefox):

```
-moz-linear-gradient
```

You might like the site [CSS3Please](http://css3please.com/)! which lets you see how to apply all these various properties, and generates the code for all browsers (even Opera, which most people often forget but which they really really shouldn't. So sayeth a diehard Opera user.) There's also [ColorZilla's Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), which I've found to be a little less intuitive...but it does generate the CSS styledefs as well.